# Cucumber, Capybara & Rails 2.3.2 - FactoryGirl not committing records to database, but works from console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, cucumber, integration-testing

I have a strange problem, when I run my (only / first) cucumber test, part of which creates a new entry in my Countries table using:

```
Factory.create(:country)
```

the models don't get committed to my database (MySql 5) & my test fails as the view tries to load this data. Here is a snippet from my test.log

```
  [4;36;1mSQL (0.1ms)[0m   [0;1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [4;35;1mCountry Create (0.1ms)[0m   [0mINSERT INTO `countries` (`name`, `country_code`, `currency_code`) VALUES('Ireland', 'IE', 'EUR')[0m
  [4;36;1mSQL (0.1ms)[0m   [0;1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [4;35;1mSQL (0.1ms)[0m   [0mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
```

However when I load up the rails console and run exactly the same command i.e. Factory.create(:country), the records get committed to the database. Here is the output from  test.log

```
[4;36;1mSQL (3.5ms)[0m   [0;1mBEGIN[0m
  [4;35;1mCountry Create (0.2ms)[0m   [0mINSERT INTO `countries` (`name`, `country_code`, `currency_code`) VALUES('Ireland', 'IE', 'EUR')[0m
  [4;36;1mSQL (1.1ms)[0m   [0;1mCOMMIT[0m
```

From env.rb

```
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Any advise is very much appreciated, I've spent the last two days trying to figure this out but had no success.

Answer (score 0):

The second line of what you posted from your `test.log` file shows the record being inserted. I see that you've turned off transactional fixtures, which is fine.

Are you using the `database_cleaner` gem by chance? If so, it's going to essentially roll your database back to its original state after the tests are done. This means that, unless you pause your tests while they're running, and after data is inserted, you'll never see it in the DB because it gets removed after the test suite is run.

I don't know that this is what's causing the issue at the root of the thing, but it would definitely explain why, when you run just that one command from the console, that you see it in the DB, but you don't after you run your tests. The test data is **supposed** to be removed after the test suite executes, so your tests have a fresh, consistent starting point for each run. It's an important part of making sure that your tests run in the same environment every time, and therefore can be counted upon to give you reliable results.

Comment: When I added database_cleaner & set DatabaseCleaner.strategy = nil - the records started to save. However from my test.log file I can see that while the records are being created at the start of the tests, they don't become available to the app / view until the next time I run my test cases - its like the first time I run the test cases the data gets inserted & the tests fail (no data), then next time they find the data & pass. Any ideas? Thanks!